# Is switching topics a viable SEO strategy or will it harm existing ranking?

Tags: seo, google

I acquired a 16 year old authority blog about medieval armor, and it ranks #1 in all search engines for many armor related terms and how to's, 100% of the traffic (about 6k-7k visitors / month) comes from either search or referrals.

I've been thinking of ways to try to expand the number of visitors and I noticed the commercial "body armor" market gets a lot of traffic.

So is it viable to make an SEO leap from armor in the medieval sense to armor in the modern sense of body armor?  Or will attempting to do this harm the existing search ranking?

Answer (score 1):

It will very likely dilute how your site is found and can ultimately effect bounce rates when users click on links for antique armor and find something else negatively effecting how a site performs. SERP CTR and bounce rates are a major factor.

It would be too fuzzy differentiating the difference between the two. I would advise against it. Go for another domain if you want modern armor as a topic.

Comment: That was my main concern, I'm experimenting with categorization but I just have a gut feeling it will dilute my existing rankings somehow.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been thinking of ways to try to expand the number of visitors and I noticed the commercial "body armor" market gets a lot of traffic.
>   So is it viable to make an SEO leap from armor in the medieval sense to armor in the modern sense of body armor?

Why not combine the two instead of switching? 
After all, you say you have 6-7k visitors a month about medieval armor. If you also add a section to your site called body armor, then the odds of you gaining visitors go up because you're integrating both topics into one site. You visitors total may be 6-7k plus the number of expected visitors seeking body armor.

Comment: Right, I did begin experimenting with this last week by writing a few blog posts about body armor relating to news I picked up from Google alerts - this probably isn't the best way of doing it so I'm going to have some original (4,000+ word) content produced to expand upon this test.

Comment: Another observation I've made is that the audience affinity / interests are dominated by 'Hardcore Gamers' - so maybe that's another potential opportunity that's perhaps even bigger than body armor - a lot of popular games have armor as a key component within the game.